# Show next id and animation on user scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

First I use an library to animate going from #one to #two with this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

my html is:

```
<div id="indicators">

    <a href="#one" class="btn page-scroll" style="border-radius: 50%;"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
    <a href="#two" class="btn page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
    <a href="#three" class="btn page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
    </div>
```

so now when I click on some indicator (circle icon) send me with animation to ther div but what I want to do now is when user have focus on some div and when scroll down to show to them new #id with animation...

etc. user have focus in #two and when scroll down a little to show them #three with animation ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(body).scroll(function(){

//if user is on #one on scroll go to the #two with animation
    });
});
```